# How does Hibernate perform synchronization with the database when using the 2nd-level Cache

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, ehcache

Recently, I have started working with Hibernate.

I just wanted to know and clear my doubt about how does Hibernate do synchronization of 2nd-level cache (e.g. Ehcache) with the database (implicitly or explicitly).

Or, do we have to always use the Hibernate API (e.g. session.flush()) to keep the 2nd-level Cache in sync with database explicitly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 2nd level [CacheConcurrencyStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CacheConcurrencyStrategy.html#NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE) defines how the cache and the database are synchronized, so:

- [NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-nonstrict_read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) is a [read-though](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cache-synchronization-strategies/) cache using soft locks
- [READ_WRITE](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-read_write-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) is an asynchronous write-though cache using soft locks
- [TRANSACTIONAL](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-hibernate-transactional-cacheconcurrencystrategy-work/) is a synchronous write-though cache

Comment: thank you Vlad for reply. I had idea of this earlier but I haven't understand the concept in literal sense. like, Suppose I have inserted or updated any record in DB, now what will happen in case of each of three mentioned above.? It could be a silly question but I'm not getting how caching will behave in above three scenarios..?

Comment: If you update the DB without Hibernate to know about it, you have to set cache expiry to avoid stale entries.

Comment: I'm updating DB only with HQL, I'm using below annotation with my entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

Just confirm that using above annotation will Ehcache get update automatically..?

Comment: Yes. You should be fine in that case.

Comment: Thank you very much Vlad Mihalcea.